# "Anyone has" or "anyone have" seen them?

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-number, pronouns

So I thought I'm sure about this and my instincts say that: "If anyone has seen them .." would be right but then again when I said it like: "If anyone have seen them .." I started thinking which one would be the right one.
Can you please guide me through which is the right one and why?
P.S. English is not my first language.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's "if anyone has", because "anyone" functions as third person singular. It probably just seems right to use "have" because you would for any other number or person.

Comment: I have a related question: what would the correct usage in : Does anyone has or have

Answer (score 3):

If you break the word down as "any one", you can tell which is correct:

> if any one **has** seen them