# Anyone: ("they" or "he/she") why is it sometimes plural?

Tags: grammar, pronouns, singular-they

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Is it correct to use “their” instead of “his or her”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/192/is-it-correct-to-use-their-instead-of-his-or-her)

Plural versus singular:

> Anyone can learn to dance if **they** want to.
>
> Anyone can learn to dance if **he or she** wants to.

Resources online tell me that anyone is a singular indefinite pronoun. Then why is it sometimes acceptable to use the plural 'they' with 'anyone' in some cases? Does it substitute and replace 'he/she'?

note: this previous posts also says anyone is [singular]: ["Anyone has" or "anyone have" seen them?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/23218/anyone-has-or-anyone-have-seen-them)

Comment: With regards to the note, *anyone* **is** singular, but so is *they* when used with it—hence the term "singular *they*"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Singular They](http://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-the2.htm):

> Merriam-Webster’s Dictionary of English Usage remarks that “**They, their, them** have been used continuously in **singular reference** for about six centuries, and have been disparaged in such use for about two centuries. Now the influence of social forces is making their use even more attractive.”