# Present perfect tense question

Tags: grammar, present-perfect

Anyone has xxx's mobile number?
or 
Anyone have xxx's mobile number?

Which is correct?

Comment: There is no present perfect in your sentences. The only difference is that one sentence treats _anyone_ as singular, the other as plural. Can you please explain what your actual question is? You probably would want to do that on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com) by the way.

Comment: This is about verb agreement and not tense. Also, there is no present perfect tense in either example. You should look it up. Lastly, please [search the site before asking](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/23218/anyone-has-or-anyone-have-seen-them). Thanks.